# How to switch column values in the same Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following DataFrame:

[image]

I need to switch values of col2 and col3 with the values of col4 and col5. Values of col1 will remain the same. The end result needs to look as the following:

[image]

Is there a way to do this without looping through the DataFrame?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [rename](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) in pandas

```
In [160]: df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],'B':[3,4,5]})

In [161]: df
Out[161]:
   A  B
0  1  3
1  2  4
2  3  5

In [167]: df.rename({'B':'A','A':'B'},axis=1)
Out[167]:
   B  A
0  1  3
1  2  4
2  3  5
```

Answer (score 3):

This should do:

```
og_cols = df.columns
new_cols = [df.columns[0], *df.columns[3:], *df.columns[1:3]]
df = df[new_cols] # Sort columns in the desired order
df.columns = og_cols # Use original column names
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to swap the column values:

```
df.iloc[:, 1:3], df.iloc[:, 3:] = df.iloc[:,3:].to_numpy(copy=True), df.iloc[:,1:3].to_numpy(copy=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Pandas `reindex` could help :

```
cols = df.columns

#reposition the columns
df = df.reindex(columns=['col1','col4','col5','col2','col3'])
#pass in new names
df.columns = cols
```